# matching two curves

Tags: data-analysis

I have two curves extracted from some data and I'm trying to detect when there is a difference. Each of these 3 plots represents a different data set.

From these example curves below, I'm looking for a metric that I can use to compare the green and blue plots. These are normalised plots.

The Left and Right plots are examples of a matching case.
The middle plot is an example of non-matching data set.

I've tried using Chi-Square and Bhattacharyya distance but neither give good separation between data sets.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Given that these are curves of the form $y=f(x)$, i.e., graphs of some functions, you can use one of popular norms on function spaces, such as:

- uniform norm $\max_{a\le x\le b} |f(x)-g(x)|$
- $L^1$ norm $\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)|\,dx$
- $L^2$ norm $\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)|^2\,dx$

(Integrals become sums for discrete data).

I would probably go with $L^2$ distance, which from the appearance of the curves should be substantially larger for the plot in the middle.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the problem is that the third graph, on the right, has a slight offset in X so there is a large accumulated difference between the two curves.

Comment: @Oliver9523 Perhaps the [Fréchet distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distance) could help?